# Can a non-proper variety contain a proper curve

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves, schemes, arithmetic-geometry, projective-schemes

Let $f:X\to S$ be a  finite type, separated but non-proper morphism of schemes.

Can there be a projective curve $g:C\to S$ and a closed immersion $C\to X$ over $S$?

Just to be clear: A projective curve is a smooth projective morphism $X\to S$ such that the geometric fibres are geometrically connected and of dimension 1.

In simple layman's terms: Can a non-projective variety contain a projective curve?

Feel free to replace "projective" by "proper". It probably won't change much.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure, $\mathbb{P}_k^2-\{pt\}$ is not proper over $Spec(k)$ and contains a proper $\mathbb{P}_k^1$.

Comment: this is a closed immersion right? Any higher genus examples?

Comment: Yes, john's example easily generalizes so that if you have any smooth projective curve $C$ embedded in some $\mathbb{P}^n$, you can always consider the closed immersion $C \hookrightarrow \mathbb{P}^n \setminus \{x\}$ for a point $x \in \mathbb{P}^n \setminus C$.